# Confusion over non-commutativity of linear differential operators

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Where $D$, differentiation, is a linear differential operator:

I am trying to understand the transform of the following into the form of a polynomial in $D$ over $C$, the space of all continuous functions on some interval: 
$$(xD + 1)[(D-x)y]$$

So, I follow this far:

$$(xD + 1)[(D-x)y]$$
$$= (xD + 1)(\frac{dy}{dx} - xy)$$
$$= x \frac{dy}{dx} (\frac{dy}{dx} - xy) + \frac{dy}{dx} - xy$$
$$= x(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx} - y) + \frac{dy}{dx} - xy$$

In this last line here... the $ - y$, the third term in the first group of parentheses in the last line, where is this coming from??!  I have a pretty good grasp of a lot of this, but I am stuck, I cannot understand this yet!

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the product rule
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=y+x\frac{dy}{dx},
$$
and it should probably be written (note that I don't write $\frac{dy}{dx}$ outside the parenthesis, but only $\frac{d}{dx}$)
$$
\begin{gathered}
x\frac{d}{dx}\bigl(\frac{dy}{dx}-xy\bigr)+\frac{dy}{dx}-xy\\
=x\bigl(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-y-x\frac{dy}{dx}\bigr)+\frac{dy}{dx}-xy.
\end{gathered}
$$

Comment: Got it.  Great, thank you.